# Performing a Segue in webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest and returning 'NO'

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, segue

I have a UIWebView that loads a page with an html button. When user taps that button, "http://somerequest" is loaded.

I am capturing the request in shouldStartLoadWithRequest (in the code below) and when "http://somerequest" is requested, a segue is performed with identifier "Comments":

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *url = [request URL];


    if([[url absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"http://somerequest"])
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Comments" sender:self];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

"performSegueWithIdentifier" is working properly but the shouldStartLoadWithRequest function is not returning "NO". If I remove "performSegueWithIdentifier", the function is able to return NO.

Please tell me how I can perform the segue when the UIWebView requests "http//somerequest" and does not load the request in current UIWebView (by returning 'NO').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    BOOL returnValue = YES;

    if([[url absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"http://somerequest"])
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Comments" sender:self];

        returnValue =  NO;
    }


    return returnValue;
}
```

Any way set a break point to make sure ' returnValue =  NO;' is called.
Shani

Comment: Not working. Whenever [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Comments" sender:self] is called, function returns YES;

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint to make sure that 'return YES;' is not being called ?

Comment: Your answer is correct, it was actually some jQuery mobile related issue I was having.